# Как отправить сообщение нескольким CHAT_ID в PHP (Телеграмбот)?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Каким образом отправить сообщение нескольким лицам в тег-боте, сейчас отправляется только одному лицу:

```
$send_data['chat_id'] = "198130336,42837823211";
```

что то вроде того как сделать? если в строке несколько CHat_ID, разделенные запятой ("198130336,42837823211"):

```
foreach($send_data['chat_id'] as $sa){
$mess = sendTelegram($method, $sa);
}
```

Comment: строку с id делите по разделителю (запятой), получаете массив. Циклом бежите по нему и каждому отправляете сообщение. профит

Answer (score 1):

строку с id делите по разделителю (запятой), получаете массив. Циклом бежите по нему и каждому отправляете сообщение. профит

```
<?php

$send_data['chat_id'] = "198130336,42837823211";

$ids = explode(',', $send_data['chat_id']);
foreach (  $ids as $id) {
  $mess = sendTelegram($method, $id);// тут параметры заполняйте по документации
  // а может и так
  // $mess = sendTelegram($method, trim($sa));
}
```